# merge the columns of different rows into one row group by a specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "day":     ["monday", "monday","Tuesday" ],
        "column0": ["xx",      "xx",     ""],
        "column1": ["yy",      "aa",    "bb"],
        "column2": ["cc",      "cc",    "cc"],
        "column3": ["cc",      "",      "aa"]})


    day    column0  column1 column2 column3
0   monday  xx       yy       cc      cc
1   monday  xx       aa       cc    
2   Tuesday          bb       cc      aa
```

I want to group by the day and join the columns in rows and also keep the rows an index column

Expected outcome1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "day":     ["monday", "Tuesday" ],
        "index":   ["0,1",          "2" ],
        "column0": ["xx",             ""],
        "column1": ["yy",           "bb"],
        "column2": ["cc",           "cc"],
        "column3": ["cc",           "aa"],
        "column4": ["xx",             ""],
        "column5": ["aa",             ""],
        "column6": ["cc",             ""]})

    day   index column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
0   monday  0,1   xx       yy     cc      cc      xx      aa    cc
1   Tuesday 2              bb     cc      aa
```

Finally, i want to delete the same values on each row and add NAN to blank columns

Final outcome:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "day":     ["monday", "Tuesday" ],
        "index":   ["0,1",          "2" ],
        "column0": ["xx",          "NAN"],
        "column1": ["yy",           "bb"],
        "column2": ["cc",           "cc"],
        "column3": ["NAN",          "aa"],
        "column5": ["aa",          "NAN"]})

    day   index column0 column1 column2  column3    column4
0   monday  0,1   xx      yy          cc    NAN       aa
1   Tuesday 2    NAN      bb          cc    aa        NAN
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy to flatten your grouped dataframes. Then store them in a list and make a dataframe from it.

You can finally replace `""` and `None` with `NaN`, drop `NaN` columns and rename your columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "day":     ["monday", "monday","Tuesday" ],
        "column0": ["xx",      "xx",     ""],
        "column1": ["yy",      "aa",    "bb"],
        "column2": ["cc",      "cc",    "cc"],
        "column3": ["cc",      "",      "aa"]})

arr_list = []
for d, sub_df in df1.groupby("day"):
  arr = list(np.array(sub_df.iloc[:,1:]).flatten())
  arr = [d, list(sub_df.index)] + arr
  arr_list.append(arr)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr_list)
df = df.replace('',np.nan).fillna(value=np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df.columns = ["day", "index"] + [f"column{i}" for i in range(len(df.columns)-2)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       day   index column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
0  Tuesday     [2]     NaN      bb      cc      aa     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   monday  [0, 1]      xx      yy      cc      cc      xx      aa      cc
```

###### Edit: if you want to remove duplicates in each row, do it after flattening your array.

Also you can keep the original order by specifying `sort=False` in `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {   
        "day":     ["monday", "monday","Tuesday" ],
        "column0": ["xx",      "xx",     ""],
        "column1": ["yy",      "aa",    "bb"],
        "column2": ["cc",      "cc",    "cc"],
        "column3": ["cc",      "",      "aa"]})

arr_list = []
for d, sub_df in df1.groupby("day", sort=False):
  # flattening the grouped dataframe ([:,1:] => all rows, all column except the first one: day)
  arr = list(np.array(sub_df.iloc[:,1:]).flatten())
  # removing duplicates for this row:
  arr_unique = []
  for x in arr:
    if not x in arr_unique:
      arr_unique.append(x)
    else: # appending NaN to keep dataframe form
      arr_unique.append(np.nan)
  # re-appending day and adding the indexes of the grouped rows:
  arr = [d, list(sub_df.index)] + arr_unique
  arr_list.append(arr)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr_list)
# replacing '' with NaN and dropping NaN columns:
df = df.replace('',np.nan).fillna(value=np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
# renaming columns, the first two are 'day' and 'index' the rest is generated: columnX where X goes from 0 to the nb of column minus 2 (since we already named two columns)
df.columns = ["day", "index"] + [f"column{i}" for i in range(len(df.columns)-2)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       day   index column0 column1 column2 column3 column4
0   monday  [0, 1]      xx      yy      cc     NaN      aa
1  Tuesday     [2]     NaN      bb      cc      aa     NaN
```

Comment: is it possible to keep the "order" as in my example of the final outcome? So first Monday and after that Tuesday

Comment: it should work if you give paremeter `sort=False` to `groupby`: `for d, sub_df in df1.groupby("day", sort=False):`. Editing my answer with the change right away.

Comment: in your edit section who you transform it to dataframe?

Comment: In the code in the edit section, yes. It's just the loop actually, the conversion to dataframe occurs after. (see frist code snippet)

Comment: your solution works fine. Thank you very much. Just one more request. Can you provide a unified solution (i.e merge your first code with your edit part)?

Comment: may I ask i question, please?How to keep the rows number? For example, in my expected outcome I want to have 2  Tuesday 2 inside of 1 Tuesday 2. Is this possible? I believe that i must use reset_index somewhere in your code but cannot fiqure out where

Comment: I don't really understand what you need. In this example Tuesday will appear only once since we grouped by day. Try creating a new question with a detailed description of your problem (including minimal reproducible example, input and desired output)

Comment: @ Tranbi I know that is way to much but I am trying to understand your code with little success. Can you add some comments? For example why you use this code: [:,1:]) and also this len(df.columns)-2. What does these means? Thanks in advanced

Comment: I added some comments, hope it helps! Do not hesitate to use a debugger and/or print variables along the code to understand the different transformations